# Post data with jQuery to ASP.net, am I doing this secure enough?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, security

For a website I am building, I am using jQuery to post data to Generic Handlers I created for this purpose.

Because you need to be logged in, to do most post actions (like 'rate a picture'), I am currently using the following technique:

1. User visits page
2. Page determines if user is logged in
3. On Page_Load the page fills a hidden field with an encrypted string, which contains several needed variables, like User ID, Picture ID (of the picture they are currently viewing), the DateTime when the page was rendered.
4. When the user clicks a "I like this picture"-button, I do a $.ajax post to my Generic Handler, with the encrypted string and the value whether or not they liked the picture.
5. The Generic Handler decrypts the supplied encrypted string and takes a look at the DateTime to determine if it was not too long ago
6. When everything works out, the vote is submitted to the database.

In my understanding this is a pretty secure way to handle a situation like this. But maybe I am missing a very important point here.

Any advice would be very welcome.

Comment: That seems alright, as long as you keep your secret decrypter token safe and secure.

Comment: Well that is another point of discussion ofcourse. Currently the encryption key is stored in the web.config. Which is safe enough I think?

Comment: Yes the web.config is secure. ASP.NET won't return .config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks okay to me.

It looks like you're using a token pattern, a good method with which to secure stateless communications.

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that $.ajax calls to your Handler will also support native ASP.NET security mechanism. When you perform $.ajax the .ASPXAUTH cookie is being add to cookies collection, so you can check in your Handler for this cookie, check HttpContext.User and limit access to the path of your handler in web.config - this all works.